# How to get format name from AVCaptureDeviceFormat in swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, avfoundation, ios8.1, cfstring

Here my code in objective-c

```
for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [device formats]) {

       CFStringRef formatName = CMFormatDescriptionGetExtension([format formatDescription], kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_FormatName);

}
```

I need this code in swift, how can i?

i tried like this but giving error

[image]

Comment: I need formatDescription from AVCaptureDeviceFormat